# Split group of enemies?

Tags: unity

[image].
[image].
In my script, enemy goes to dead point and if player closet to him he attacking player. When I started making wave of enemies I notes that all of them goes to player. Now, I need to add something making enemy avoid player in case there are 4 enemy around him and goes to dead_point. What I did is, I attached every player script "enemyAround" to count any enemy around player.

```
    public int enemies = 0;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    enemies++;
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    enemies--;
}
```

But I couldn't figure how to make enemy read it ?. If Enemy select player to attack him, He reads or knows How many enemy around the selected player.

enemy script

```
private Animator enemy_anim;
private NavMeshAgent mAgent;
private GameObject[] player;
public GameObject[] dead_point;
public int farPoint, dead_point_number, player_number;
public float dist;
public bool enemt_run, enemy_atack = false;
public bool near;

private enemyAround arounds;
public int enemy_around_player;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

    mAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    enemy_anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
    dead_point = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("dead_point"); // 3 points
    enemy_dirction();

}

void Update()
{

    // count enemies around player
    enemy_around_player = selected player 

    for (int i = 1; i < player.Length; i++)
    {

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player[i].transform.position) <
            Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player[player_number].transform.position))
        {
            player_number = i;
        }
    }

    dead_point_number = dead_point.Length;
    dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player[player_number].transform.position);

    if (dist <= 5)
    {
        near = true;
    }
    else
    {
        near = false;
    }


    if (player != null && dist <= 5.1f)
    {
        mAgent.destination = player[player_number].transform.position;
        if (dist < 1.2f)
        {
            enemy_atack = true;
        }
        else
        {
            enemy_atack = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (dead_point_number > 0)
        {
            mAgent.destination = dead_point[farPoint].transform.position;
        }
        else
        {
            mAgent.destination = player[player_number].transform.position;

        }
        if (mAgent.remainingDistance <= 1.5f)
        {
            enemy_atack = true;
        }
        else
        {
            enemy_atack = false;
            enemt_run = true;

        }
    }

    mAgent.speed = 1.0f;


    enemy_anim.SetBool("run", enemt_run);
    enemy_anim.SetBool("attack", enemy_atack);
}// end update


// choose any deat_point.
void enemy_dirction()
{
    if (dead_point_number > 0)
    {
        farPoint = Random.Range(0, dead_point.Length);
        mAgent.destination = dead_point[farPoint].transform.position;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```